# Doubts on storing CPU,RAM and DISK usage values

Tags: database, windows, storage

I have few doubts on database storage techniques:

1. How to store **CPU** usage activity to consider it for later use?
2. How to store **RAM** usage variation for a certain amount of time?
3. Similarly, how to store **Disk** usage?

All these data will be later used for **ANOVA** test.

I am trying to get these values from a c# application which will be monitoring the activities of a system for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better idea is to use the Performance Manager built into Windows (perfmon.exe). You can set it to record many performance items including the three you mention (CPU and RAM by program as well as in total). There is also a free analyser called PAL at [Codeplex](http://pal.codeplex.com) which can help you set the recording and then analyse it for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this :)

Comment: How to use the perfmon.exe (built in) to extract values from it?